# Sitecore Context use which database, Master, web or core?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

Sorry if my question is too basic, I can't figure out that in the code when I write:

`var myItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("....");`

Which database is used in this case, either Master Db or Web Db ? In this link, "[Context Class](https://sdn.sitecore.net/doc/api%205.0/Sitecore.Context.html)" its written that, "The Context object holds information about the current state such as current database, current language, current domain etc."

How do I know what is current? e.g. **Current Database**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sitecore data is stored in multiple databases. From a web developer’s perspective, the two most often used ones are master, which contains the data being edited in the Content Manager, and web which is storing the data used to display the web site.

Databases can be accessed through the Database class. 
To obtain a reference to a database, use the Factory class, as in:

```
 Sitecore.Data.Database master =  
    Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
```

The database names and implementation details are specified in the web.config below the  section.

Whenever the user code is invoked by Sitecore, a so called context database is automatically assigned. You can access this database by using the Context class, as in:

```
Sitecore.Data.Database current = Sitecore.Context.Database;
```

When the code executes on the web site (that is in a layout or an xsl extension), the context database will be web. When code is executing within the Content Manager, the context database will be core. The core database contains data needed by the Content Manager.

To access the database being edited within the Content Manager, you can use

```
Database content = Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase;
```

The ContentDatabase property will be empty when executing in the web site context. Only content editors (such as the Content Manager) will normally support this property.

Comment: Code on the website will not always be using the "web" database..  as it's defined in the sites definition, it can be called anything. Some implementations use multiple publishing targets to multiple databases.

Comment: Yep, I totally agree with you.

Comment: This line "When code is executing within the Content Manager, the context database will be core. " solved my issue. Thanks @VladIobagiu

Answer (score 1):

The Context Database is one your site or code is actively querying against. For your website, the default database is defined in the `<site>` definition and that becomes the "context" database for that site.  For example, by default, the "web" database is the context database for the "Website" site definition.

> `<site name="website" database="web" ...../>`

`Sitecore.Context.Database.Name` will give you the name of the current Context database.

Comment: This is not correct. In Sitecore Desktop when you switch between master, web and core you change Content database not Context database

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I was simply trying to illustrate the difference, but since the internet is permanent, I'll revise the comment to not cause confusion for future readers.

Comment: I marked this up as it actually helped me answer the question I had. The correctly marked answer is just a copy paste of sitecore documentation. Which really adds no value. So thanks again for this answer

Answer (score 0):

The context database is determined by your request (there is a databaseresolver in the httprequestbegin pipeline), but can be altered in code. This means that you question is actually not answerable.. it can be anything.

Let's assume your code is running in a (sub)layout or rendering, which seems like a correct assumption and skips the more tricky parts as core database and so on. In this case your context will be determined by the sites definition. In a standard setup this will be the "web" database. But you can define other databases (to create multiple publishing targets) and then the name could be different ("pub" ...).

In editing mode however, the context database can be different things. Normally "master" when editing, "web" when previewing...

So, as the name states - it all depends on the context in which your code is running.

Answer (score 0):

Most of it was already answered but the answer is: it depends on what part of Sitecore is being executed.
For example if you are previewing a page it by default will use the master database. But if you are viewing the published version of the site than it will use the web database.